# MS Report Builder subreport not displaying

Tags: reporting-services

Need some help guys. I created a report using MS SQL 2012 Server Report Builder 3.0, with subreport. (subreport does not have parameters) It always displays blank. I checked the visibility and it is set to visible.
This is the [main report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FW9U.png), and this is the [subreport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AbTd.png).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a Data Set within your subreport and this Data Set must return at least 1 row of data.

You can use for example this hack (If you otherwise don't need Data Set):

1. Add a Data Source with connection to database
2. Add new Data Set to your subreport
3. Use this query in your Data Set

   `Select 1 as value`